# C++ Function Pointers to an Object

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers, functor, pointer-to-member

I'm not sure if this is possible in C++. I know you can pass a pointer to a function or static member function as a parameter. I want a function pointer for a specific object, so that when the function is executed, it is done on the object.

```
class MyClass
{
   public:
      MyClass(int id){mId = id;}
      void execute(){cout<<mId<<endl;}
   private:
      int mId;
};


MyClass obj1(1);
MyClass obj2(2);

typedef (Executor)();
Executor ex1 = &obj1::execute();
Executor ex2 = &obj2::execute();
```

So when ex1 is executed, "1" should be printed and if ex2 is execute, "2" is printed. Is this possible?

Comment: look at {std,boost}::function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The facility that handles this is the function template [`bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

```
auto ex1 = std::bind(&MyClass::execute, obj1);
```

You can store a bind in a `function` object:

```
std::function<void()> ex1 = std::bind(&MyClass::execute, obj1);
```

Note that by default `bind` will store `obj` by value; you can store a reference with `ref`:

```
std::function<void()> ex1 = std::bind(&MyClass::execute, std::ref(obj1));
```

A related facility is `mem_fn`, which wraps a member function pointer:

```
void (MyClass::*ex1)() = &MyClass::execute;  // raw member function pointer
ex1(obj1);

auto ex1 = std::mem_fn(&MyClass::execute);   // mem_fn wrapper
ex1(obj)
```

However, because `mem_fn` doesn't bind an instance, you have to supply the instance each time you call it.

---

In order to avoid writing the class name when binding a member function, you can use a macro:

```
#define BIND_MEM_FN(o,m) \
    std::bind(&std::remove_reference<decltype(o)>::type::m, (o))
```

A macro is necessary because you can only form a member function pointer from its type and name, and you cannot pass a name (an *unqualified-id*) to a function.

Comment: `std::mem_fn` has some related functionality which may be of interest to the OP, though the invocation of a member function pointer isn't quite as neat as the invocation of a bind, as you have to pass the instance in as an explicit parameter.

Comment: Didn't know there was something like this in C++ STL. I wanted to write my own. Isn't there a way where you can simple say obj::execute, without having to pass the function (&MyClass::execute) and the the object (obj)? So basically a way of automatically detecting that obj (in obj::execute) is not a class and the interpreting it as an object.

Comment: And this is for C++11, isn't there a way (or maybe a macro) for this in the older version?

Comment: @goocreations - boost::bind()/boost::function() will work for those without c++11 support. And not there is no "auto-detection"

Comment: @goocreations in older versions of C++ you can use `std::bind1st` with `std::mem_fun` and store the result in `boost::function`; see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/function/tutorial.html#id1545718

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but not the way you describe it.
You can do it the way proposed by the above comments but more elegant and C++ way would be to use functors.
Functor is basically an object which has operator `()` overloaded. 
In your case it can be something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
   public:
       MyClass(int id){mId = id;}
       void operator()(){cout<<mId<<endl;}
   private:
   int mId;
};

MyClass obj1(1);
MyClass obj2(2);

obj1();
obj2();
```

This way your object actually mimics function behavior.
Here you can read more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_C_and_C.2B.2B

Comment: I don't really want to use functors. In this case you always have to put your implementation in the () operator. And if you do it in a different function, you need a lot of overhead code.

Comment: In this case you can have a pointer to member as your class data member and set it to an appropriate private method in the constructor. The `operator ()` will just have to call the method pointed by that data member. This way you can benefit from both worlds. And you also have no encapsulation violation.

Comment: Yip, that was what I meant. I want a solution that is as "clean" as possible. I think I'll go with you idea. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Member function pointers:

```
typedef void (MyClass::*Executor)();
Executor ex1 = &MyClass::execute;
Executor ex2 = &MyClass::execute;

obj1.*ex1();
obj2.*ex2();
```

**EDIT:** Corrected the code as mentioned in the comments.

I made a mistake because I rarely use (member) function pointers indeed. But not because I use std::bind, but because I use polymorphism :)

Actually I don't remember the last time I used a (member) function pointer except in interfacing with OS APIs. Member function pointers are better than non-member function pointers, and std::bind/std::function might be better than member function pointers, but polymorphism is better than all of the above.

Comment: Maybe I've made a simple mistake, but I'm getting the following error: _ISO C++ forbids taking the address of a bound member function to form a pointer to member function._ Seems like you'd be better off with `std::bind` or `std::mem_fn`.